# Arrow function in render Vs. attribute to carry data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Developing in REACT, I've faced multiple times the needing of passing an item into a function, for example doing so:

```
// Inside a Hook component
return (
  ...
  {nodes.map(n => <Node data={node} onClick={(e) => handleNodeClick(e, node)} />)}
);
```

Basically, I have a variable `nodes`, which could come from `props`, `useMemo`, ... anything. Then, I create a `<Node>` component for each node.
Finally, as you can see, `<Node>` component has a `onClick` props, which trigger a function. In THAT function I need the node, with all its data (imagine a node of a tree, with an uniqueID, icon, ...).

So, writing as in the example, I achieve what I need, BUT! I have an arrow function in the return statement, and I've also read that it's NOT good to have an arrow function in the `render()` method.. And I guess the same is for the `return` statement inside an Hook component.

Thus, to overcome the use of arrow function, several times I've used attribute to avoid that. Basically, something like this:

```
// Inside a Hook component
const handleNodeClick = (e) => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
    const nodeDOM = e.target.closest('[data-is-node]');

    if (nodeDOM) {
      const nodeIndex = e.target.getAttribute("data-node-index");
      const node = nodes[nodeIndex];

      ...
    }
  }
}

return (
  ...
  {nodes.map((n, i) => <Node
    data={node}
    data-is-node={''}
    data-node-index={i}
    onClick={handleNodeClick2} />)}
);
```

So, as you can see, eventually, in `handleNodeClick2` I do have the `node` I need. But, I wonder if all I need to do is worth it, or should I just use an arrow function.

Hope I've explained the question good enough. Especially, I'm not even sure if the phrase *"no arrow function inside the `render()` method"* applies also for Hook component.

Comment: Just use an arrow function. With this kind of stuff its *technically* less performant, but you'll hardly every notice it. Its better to go with the more readable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the simplicity of an arrow function without the complexity you've tried, you *can* create a higher order function that takes the `node` you want to pass to the callback and returns a callback function.

```
// Higher Order Function to enclose `node` in function scope to be used later
// Function takes a node parameter and returns an event handler function
const handleNodeClick = node => e => {
  // node in function scope
  // do what you need
  ...
}

return (
  ...
  {nodes.map((node, i) => (
    <Node
      data={node}
      data-is-node={""}
      data-node-index={i}
      onClick={handleNodeClick2(node)}
    />
  ))}
);
```

Anonymous inner arrow functions are usually perfectly fine to use within the render function. The reason it is sometimes discouraged are the cases where you are essentially passing *the same* callback *implementation* to a bunch of elements being mapped, each mapped element get's an entire copy of the function. Creating and instantiating all these callback functions may not be expensive, but there is a cost associated. In cases like this the pattern is to simply define a named arrow function callback (once) and pass the reference to it.

```
items.map(item => <button onClick={e => { /* expensive callback code */}}>{item}</button>)
```

versus

```
const expensiveCallback = e => { /* expensive callback code */};

...

items.map(item => <button onClick={expensiveCallback}>{item}</button>)
```

You can take it a step further if you're concerned and factor out the map's callback too

```
const expensiveCallback = e => { /* expensive callback code */};
const renderItemButton = item => <button onClick={expensiveCallback}>{item}</button>;

...

items.map(renderItemButton)
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Just a question to be sure I've understood. You said that *"The reason it is sometimes discouraged are the cases where you are essentially passing the same callback implementation"*: in my case, where the arrow function is just `onClick={(e) => handleNodeClick(e, node)}`, each item gets a copy of just this little function, or get a copy even of `handleNodeClick`?
Because, in the first case, I'm positive to say that the cost wouldn't bother, but in the second.. It may depends from the `handleNodeClick` implementation

Comment: Each gets an instance of the defined inline function `e => handleNodeClick(e, node)`. Here `handleNodeClick` is defined externally to *this* function so it is merely invoking it when it executes. Discouragement is when some put more logic in this anonymous function.